# Very high intercept in log-normal linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, logarithm

I ran multiple linear regression in R.
I have a skewed Y variable and log transforming it gives better results. I didn't transform any of the x variables. Thus, in order to interpret the coefficients I need to exponentiate the coefficients and once doing that I receive a very high intercept value:

[Coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc6Ah.png)

Please find my code below:

```
ols_log <- lm(log(Inc_sales) ~.-Page_nr, data = train)
summary(ols_log)
rmse_log<-rmse(actual=log(train$Inc_sales), predicted =ols_log$fitted.values)
rmse_log
matrix_coef <- summary(ols_log)$coefficients
ols_log_estimates <- matrix_coef[,1]
ols_log_estimates

#Interpretation of the log coefficients
exp <-(exp(ols_log_estimates)-1)*100
exp <-format(exp, scientific=FALSE)
exp 
table(exp)

exp %>%
  kbl(caption = "Coefficients in %") %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Times New Roman")
```

Do I interpret correctly that for every one-unit increase in x, y increases by about 48000%?
How can I have such a high intercept and how could I fix it?

image with summary(log_ols):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't use R routinely but if this guess is wrong that will be spotted quickly enough. I guess that `log()` in R means natural logarithms and your use of `exp()` as inverse implies that too. So far, so good.

Either way, suppose that you used natural logarithms so that your fitted model gives predictions of the form

$$\ln y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \cdots$$

so that you are led to think in terms of getting predictions

$$y = \exp(b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \cdots).$$ However, that is not at all the same as

$$y = \exp(b_0) + \exp(b_1 x_1) + \exp(b_2 x_2) + \cdots$$

as you may be assuming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Nick! However can you please explain a bit more why it would not be the same? and in that case how I can interpret the intercept?

Comment: For the same reason as that $\exp(p q) = \exp(p) \exp(q)$ not $\exp(p) + \exp(q)$.  See any exposition of exponential functions. The intercept $b_0$ is what is predicted for $\ln y$ when the rest of the RHS is zero. Is that even attainable with your data? Can you show `summary(ols_log)`?

Comment: I am not sure indeed if it is attainable as I have mostly categorical variables. I attached the image of `summary(ols_log)` at the end of my post.

Comment: Suffice it to say that -- as far as I can see -- the intercept has no useful interpretation in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: If I'm not asking for too much, I'm also not sure why am I getting NA's for some coefficients and the message above the coefficients: 2 not defined because of singularities? i know that this might mean that independent variables are perfectly collinear, however in my case this happens to factors of one variable.

Comment: In general, the comments are not for supplementary questions, but here that looks standard: if a factor variable has $k$ categories, you will get coefficients for only $k - 1$ just as an indicator variable for a binary predictor implies $1$ coefficient to be estimated not $2$ for the two states $0$ and $1$,